# Get json file within subfolder of zip file without extracting

Tags: php

I am trying to get the 32424df344.json file within folder of zip file

File Structure:

- politi.zip
  -> tweet folder
  -> 32424df344.json file

```php
<?php
$z = new ZipArchive();
if ($z->open(dirname(__FILE__) . '/politi.zip')) {
     $json = $z->getFromName("32424df344.json");
     if ($json) {
            //decode json array
            $json_array = json_decode($json);
            var_dump($json_array);
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?  Does this code work?  If it doesn't, do you see any errors?  If the file is in a `tweet` folder, don't you need to use that when getting the file?  Like `tweet/32424df344.json`?

Comment: Also, it may be easier to use the `zip://` wrapper and change this code to use `$json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/politi.zip#tweet/32424df344.json');`

Comment: The code is getting the file  that is in main zip folder but i want the file that is in folder of zip file

Comment: Then you need to add `tweet/` to the `getFromName` call.  Or use `file_get_contents` as I suggested (instead of `ZipArchive`).

Comment: I used file_get_contents() it gives error  "failed to open stream: No such file or directory "

Comment: Thanks working by adding tweet/ to the getFromName